# Cannot get select option to POST to email php

Tags: php, email, select

I am trying to send the value of a user-selected option to an email address using the code below, but the value isn't appearing in the email after it's sent.

Here's my form:

```
<!-- contact form -->
            <form action="plugins/contact-form.php" method="post" class="form contact-form">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label for="contact-name"><strong>Name</strong> (required)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="contact-name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label for="contact-email"><strong>Email</strong> (required)</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" value="" id="contact-email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-3 last">
                        <label for="contact-www"><strong>Subject</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" value="" id="contact-www">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-1-1">
                    <select name="feedback" id="feedback">
                    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="2">Saab</option>
                    <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
                    <option value="4">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-1-1 last">
                        <label for="contact-message"><strong>Message</strong> (required)</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" cols="88" rows="6" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" class="large invert">
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </form>
            <!-- /contact form -->
```

Here's my .php:

```
<?php

// Get email address
require_once 'config.php';

// Ensures no one loads page and does simple spam check
if(isset($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['spam-check'])) {

    // Declare our $errors variable we will be using later to store any errors
    $error = '';

    // Setup our basic variables
    $input_name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $input_email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $input_subject = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);
    $feedback = array(1 => "Volvo", 2 => "Saab", 3 => "Mercedes", 4 => "Audio");
    $feedback = $feedback[(int) $_POST['feedback']];
    $input_message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

    // We'll check and see if any of the required fields are empty
    if(strlen($input_name) < 2) $error['name'] = 'Please enter your name.';
    if(strlen($input_message) < 5) $error['message'] = 'Please leave a message.';

    // Make sure the email is valid
    if(!filter_var($input_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) $error['email'] = 'Please enter a valid email address.';

    // Set a subject & check if custom subject exist
    $subject = "Message from $input_name";
    if($input_subject ) $subject .= ": $input_subject";

    $message = "$input_message\n";
    $message .= "\n---\nThis email was sent by contact form.";
    $feedback = "$feedback";

    // Now check to see if there are any errors 
    if(!$error) {

        // No errors, send mail using conditional to ensure it was sent
        if(mail($your_email_address, $subject, $message, "From: $input_email")) {
            echo '<p class="success">Your email has been sent!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">There was a problem sending your email!</p>';
        }

    } else {

        // Errors were found, output all errors to the user
        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br /> \n" : null;

        echo "<p class='warning'>$response</p>";

    }

} else {

    die('Direct access to this page is not allowed.');

}
```

Comment: `$message .= "$feedback";` you set $feedback instead of the message.

Answer (score 0):

I think error is here:

```
$message = "$input_message\n";
$message .= "\n---\nThis email was sent by contact form.";
$feedback = "$feedback";
```

You should replace last line with:

```
$message .= $feedback;
```

Comment: Thank you, man! I just fixed it before I got here. You're right.